# Container can't access /dev/ttyS0 mounted from host

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am using Docker Swarm. My service runs with host's `/dev` mounted as `/mydev`. I have given 777 permission to `/dev/ttyS0` on the host (`chmod 777 /dev/ttyS0`). However, when I try to read the device from inside of the container, I'm getting:

```sh
I have no name!@ea348bfdf7e1:/hostdev$ cat ttyS0
cat: ttyS0: Operation not permitted
```

Here's the result of `ls -lah /mydev/ttyS0` (from within the container):

```
crwxrwxrwx 1 root dialout 4, 64 Sep 27 07:05 /hostdev/ttyS0
```

Why the container does not have access even with 777 permissions on the file?

Comment: [maybe you need --device ?](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/pull/1355)

Comment: Hmm, why file binding is not enough? I though that "everything is a file" in Unix and Linux

Comment: Non-swarm docker needs --privileged to access devices. [Appears to be still an open issue for swarm.](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1030)